# rubymine でファイル名を一括置換したい

Tags: rubymine

ファイル名を一括置換したいのですが、どうするのがよいのでしょうか？

ターミナルでやっていますか？

Comment: ファイル名をgrepして一括置換したいのです。

Answer (score 1):

⇧F6で、参照箇所(requireしている箇所など)を含めて変更できます。